# Schengen visa for someone with a UK visa

Tags: visas, schengen, uk-residents

I am in the UK on a Tier 4 Student visa. Would I need a Schengen visa to travel to European countries? And if so, can I apply from within the UK?

Comment: @Newton: not a duplicate, since an UK visa is not a Schengen visa.

Comment: my bad, mis-clicked

Answer (score 5):

A UK residence permit does not exempt you from a Schengen visa. So if your nationality requires one, you need it.

You can, of course, apply through an embassy in the UK

Comment: For reference, [here's a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_in_the_European_Union#Visa_exemptions) of the countries whose citizens do not require a visa to enter the Schengen area.